# GLSL (WebGL) equivalent for RWTexture2D<float4>

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl, hlsl

### tl;dr:

I'm a shader newbie and I'm trying to port an HLSL shader to GLSL.
What is the GLSL equivalent for `RWTexture2D<float4> whatever;` ?

I need to programmatically create a texture inside a shader.

### Longer version:

I'm trying to port the "slime shader" from [this video](https://youtu.be/X-iSQQgOd1A?t=721) to GLSL, and load it in a web page (at the moment I'm using Three.js).
I managed to code the pseudo-random *hash* function and display the noise on screen, but now I'm stuck.
[(Here's the HLSL shader code)](https://github.com/SebLague/Slime-Simulation/blob/6864df9aefa2a831070a9b1e7b1caef382e98043/Assets/Scripts/Slime/SlimeSim.compute)

In the original shader there is this: `RWTexture2D<float4> TrailMap;` and I can't find a way to make something similar in my shader. All the info that I have found online is about loading external textures, but what I need is a texture that is created and modified inside the shader (and it seems to me that the way GLSL handles textures is not very beginner friendly).

I also tried using [this converter](https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/EgorYusov/20170717/301789/Stateoftheart_HLSL_to_GLSL_Converter.php). What I get is `uniform image2D TrailMap;` but it gives me  this error:

> 'image2D' : Illegal use of reserved word

What am I missing?

Comment: Try replacing `image2D` with `sampler2D`

Comment: @Rojo: You can't write to a sampler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebGL doesn't have access to [image load/store](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store), the ability to modify image data arbitrarily within shaders. The converter is doing the right thing, but WebGL simply doesn't provide access to this hardware functionality.